# EF6 EntityTypeConfiguration & SQL Alter Table -> Works in OrmLite but anything similar in EF6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ormlite-servicestack

I started off with OrmLite and now I am trying to see if I can do the same thing with Entity Framework Code First.

I have run into two areas where I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent with Entity Framework.

The first is I am using the EntityTypeConfiguration method.  With OrmLite I can have a POCO with the following:

```
public List<string> SecondaryPartNumbers { get; set; }
```

And OrmLite will blob the list to the database.  I have tried to store and retrieve values and all works as expected.  When I try to use the same line in the Entity Framework POCO I get an intellisense error at:

```
Property(x => x.SecondaryPartNumbers);
```

"the type must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T'"

I could not find any examples that show doing this with EF6.  I am guessing that EF6 is not able to work with these and I will have to create another POCO and mapping to normalize this to another table.  I really liked that OrmLite can work with a simple list of strings without having to create tables for every one.

The second question I have is how to get EF6 to modify the database table after it is created so that varbinary(max) columns are changed to filestream columns.  I am currently using this code with OrmLite (Thanks to hross: [OrmLite With Filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535267/ormlite-with-filestream)):

```
public static class OrmLiteFileStreamExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// WARNING: this will drop all of the existing varbinary columns!
    /// </summary>
    public static void UpdateByteToBinary<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn)
    {
        var modelDef = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition;
        var tableName = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedTableName(modelDef);
        var definitions = modelDef.FieldDefinitions.Where<FieldDefinition>(f => f.FieldType == typeof(byte[]));

        foreach (var def in definitions)
        {
            var columnName = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedColumnName(def.FieldName);

            dbConn.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()", tableName));

            dbConn.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} DROP COLUMN {1}", tableName, columnName));
            dbConn.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD {1} [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM NULL", tableName, columnName));
        }
    }

}
```

I have been looking around the DbContext and EntityTypeConfiguration classes to see if there is a way after the tables are created to do the same thing.  I see that there is Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() which looks to be along the right track.

The only other strategy that I have found that looks promising is to inherit an existing initializer or create one from IDatabaseInitializer and put the database code into the overridden Seed() or Initialize() methods?

But even using this I am not sure how to find and go through all the entities looking for byte[] columns and then execute the SQL code to alter the tables.

Is the above possible in Entity Framework?  I did find articles referring to Entity Framwork treating the filestream columns as varbinary(max) but everything seemed to refer to database first and not how to get the tables made from code first.

Comment: Since writing this I thought about creating a similar extension method to dbcontext and passing in a class.  Then use reflection to find the name of the byte[] property and generate similar SQL using ExecuteSqlCommand.  But I am curious if there is a way to navigate the entity framework model structure to find this out in a similar way to OrmLite.